# Is it correct to convert a CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> to a Publisher<T>?

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, project-reactor, completable-future

To allow multiple iterations on the resulting stream from a `CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>` I am considering one of the following approaches:

1. Convert the resulting future to `CompletableFuture<List<String>>` through: `teams.thenApply(st -> st.collect(toList()))`
2. Convert the resulting future to `Flux<String>` with cache: `Flux.fromStream(teams::join).cache();`

`Flux<T>` is the implementation of `Publisher<T>` in project reactor.

**Use case:**

I would like to get a sequence with the premier league teams names (e.g. `Stream<String>`) from a data source which provides a `League` object with a `Standing[]` (based on football-data RESTful API, e.g. http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/445/leagueTable). Using `AsyncHttpClient` and `Gson` we have:

```
CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> teams = asyncHttpClient
    .prepareGet("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/445/leagueTable")
    .execute()
    .toCompletableFuture()
    .thenApply(Response::getResponseBody)
    .thenApply(body -> gson.fromJson(body, League.class));
    .thenApply(l -> stream(l.standings).map(s -> s.teamName));
```

To re-use the resulting stream I have two options:

```
1. CompletableFuture<List<String>> res = teams.thenApply(st -> st.collect(toList()))

2. Flux<String> res = Flux.fromStream(teams::join).cache()
```

`Flux<T>` is less verbose and provides all that I need. Yet, is it correct to use it in this scenario?

Or should I use `CompletableFuture<List<String>>` instead? Or is there any other better alternative?

**UPDATED with some thoughts (2018-03-16)**:

`CompletableFuture<List<String>>`:

- [PROS] The `List<String>` will be collected in a continuation and when we need to proceed with the result of the future, maybe it is already completed.
- [CONS] Declaration verbosity.
- [CONS] If we just want to use it once, then we did not need to collect those items in a `List<T>`.

`Flux<String>`:

- [PROS] Declaration conciseness
- [PROS] If we just want to use it once, then we can omit `.cache()` and forward it to the next layer, which can take advantage of the reactive API, e.g. web flux reactive controller, e.g. `@GetMapping(produces =MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)   public Flux<String> getTeams() {…}`
- [CONS] If we want to reuse that `Flux<T>` we have to wrap it in a cacheable `Flux<T>` (`….cache()`) which in turn will  add overhead on the first traversal, because it has to store the resulting items in an internal cache.

Comment: "_which in turn will add overhead on the first traversal_" - negligible, ignore this.

Comment: `Flux` is an async reactive pipeline. `List` is, well a `List`. What do you **need**? You are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am not comparing `List` to `Flux`.  I am comparing a `CF<List>` to `Flux`.

Comment: That's a `Mono<List<T>>` not a `Flux<T>`. It should be obvious that the two are different.

Comment: `Mono<List<T>>` is the same as `CF<List<T>>`. NO advantage in converting from `CF<List<T>>` to `Mono<List<T>>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> teams = ...;
    Flux<String> teamsFlux = Mono.fromFuture(teams).flatMapMany(stream -> Flux.fromStream(stream));
```

`Flux.fromStream(teams::join)` is a code smell because it's blocking the current thread to fetch the result from the `CompletableFuture` which is running on another thread.

Comment: I think It does not hold the thread that invokes the `fromStream(...)`. That is lazy. We are just passing a method handle to `join` instead of invoking it. Just after a subscription maybe the pushing thread will hold on `join()`, but only if the source `CompletableFuture` has not completed yet.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have downloaded the league table, and the team names are extracted from this table, I'm not sure you need a back-pressure ready stream to iterate over these items. A conversion of the stream to a standard list (or array) should be good enough, and should probably have better performance, no?

For instance:

```
String[] teamNames = teams.join().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I am not sure about overheads. Collecting items to the `List` also induces additional overheads, isn’t it? If we are not always reusing the resulting `teams`, then creating a _cold stream_ from `Supplier::stream` maybe would be more efficient because we are not creating an auxiliary `List` object. On the other hand, if we are sure that we want to reuse `teams` then may be is better to collect it in a `List` than use `cache()`, because the later will add overhead on the first traversal. These are my doubts!!

Comment: Indeed, you can keep a stream if your intent is to read the stream once; but if you have to parse the collection of items several times, I would prefer transform the stream of items into an array of items rather than using a back-pressure ready cold stream to iterate over these items.

Comment: Not sure turning an async pipleline into a sync pipeline is the best suggestion I have ever seen.